# what does this obscene word mean?

Tags: значения, мат

There were people singning the word ХУЙЛО in the streets, but what does it mean?

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Putin_khuilo!

Comment: @KCd Amusing fact: the article about ‘Путин — хуйло!’ song exists even in Vietnamese and Arabic Wikipedias, but not in Russian.

Comment: @DmitryAlexandrov: I noticed that. There is already a separate entry on the Russian Wikipedia for the root of that word and that page has a section on current usage, but not this usage.

Comment: Is it хУйло или хуйлО?

Comment: @CocoPop _Хуйло́_. Wiktionary (both [Russian](http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%85%D1%83%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE) and [English](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%85%D1%83%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE) versions) is right here.

Comment: @KCd There was an article in Russian as well, but when I saw it a week ago, it was marked for deletion.

Comment: Urban Dictionary has it, too. http://uk.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=huylo

Answer (score 12):

Something similar to dickhead, but with way more negative connotation.

Answer (score 3):

Similar to moron, part of filthy language, with root of word `хуй`.

Answer (score 2):

We may use this word talking about a person.
"Хуйло" is a form of the word "хуй", but as we can't call a person this way we use "хуйло".
Try to avoid it.

Comment: Actually, you can call a person "хуй" - see [lurkmore.to/Ты_хуй](http://lurkmore.to/%D0%A2%D1%8B_%D1%85%D1%83%D0%B9)